# XSLT1.0 Group/Merge/Split

Tags: xslt

> I have an inbound xml file and I need to do split.

**Inbound XML file**

```
<BOM>
<Header>
    <row>
        <DocDate>20160101</DocDate>
    </row>
</Header>
<Document_Lines>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V1</Vendor>
        <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
        <BaseType>22</BaseType>
        <ItemCode>ITM00001</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Pieces>5.00000</Pieces>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V1</Vendor>
        <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
        <BaseType>22</BaseType>
        <ItemCode>ITM00002</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <Pieces>1.00000</Pieces>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V2</Vendor>
        <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
        <BaseType>22</BaseType>
        <ItemCode>ITM00008</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <Pieces>1.00000</Pieces>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V2</Vendor>
        <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
        <BaseType>22</BaseType>
        <ItemCode>ITM00009</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Pieces>2.00000</Pieces>
    </row>
</Document_Lines>
<BatchNumbers>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-1</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-2</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-3</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-4</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-5</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B1-1</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>1</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B2-1</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>2</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B3-1</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>500</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>3</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B3-2</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>500</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>3</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
</BatchNumbers>
```

> I need to split this into two segment, like this below.

**Note:**

Please look at the "Pieces" closely, that indicates a relationship between "BaseLineNumber" and "Document_Lines/row". 
In the split segment, the BaseLineNumber it should be always start from 0.
The "BaseEntry" can be used for Grouping, so, I tried to use a key match but finally failed :(

**(xsl:key name="groups" match="/BOM/Document_Lines/row" use="BaseEntry")**

**Expected Output: Split 1**

```
<BOM>
<Header>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V1</Vendor>
        <DocDate>20160101</DocDate>
    </row>
</Header>
<Document_Lines>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V1</Vendor>
        <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
        <BaseType>22</BaseType>
        <ItemCode>ITM00001</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Pieces>5.00000</Pieces>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V1</Vendor>
        <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
        <BaseType>22</BaseType>
        <ItemCode>ITM00002</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <Pieces>1.00000</Pieces>
    </row>
</Document_Lines>
<BatchNumbers>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-1</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-2</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-3</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-4</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B0-5</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B1-1</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>1</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
</BatchNumbers>
```

**Expected Output: Split 2**

```
<BOM>
<Header>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V2</Vendor>
        <DocDate>20160101</DocDate>
    </row>
</Header>
<Document_Lines>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V2</Vendor>
        <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
        <BaseType>22</BaseType>
        <ItemCode>ITM00008</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <Pieces>1.00000</Pieces>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Vendor>V2</Vendor>
        <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
        <BaseType>22</BaseType>
        <ItemCode>ITM00009</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
        <Pieces>2.00000</Pieces>
    </row>
</Document_Lines>
<BatchNumbers>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B2-1</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B3-1</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>500</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>1</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
    <row>
        <BatchNumber>B3-2</BatchNumber>
        <Quantity>500</Quantity>
        <BaseLineNumber>1</BaseLineNumber>
    </row>
</BatchNumbers>
```

In order to achieve this, I did two steps. see below output, the Step2 is what I want, but the BaseLineNumber is not correct.
I know this is a little bit complex to understand. and I am new to this website, I don't know how to directly put my code inside the reply comments instead edit.

**Step1:**

```
<BOM>
<CALL id="11003">
    <Document_Lines>
        <row>
            <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
            <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
            <BaseType>22</BaseType>
            <ItemCode>ITM08314</ItemCode>
            <ShipDate>20160224</ShipDate>
            <Quantity>3535</Quantity>
            <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>5.00000</U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
        </row>
    </Document_Lines>
    <BatchNumbers>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-1</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-2</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-3</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-4</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-5</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
    </BatchNumbers>
</CALL>
<CALL id="11003">
    <Document_Lines>
        <row>
            <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
            <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
            <BaseType>22</BaseType>
            <ItemCode>ITM07951</ItemCode>
            <ShipDate>20160224</ShipDate>
            <Quantity>566</Quantity>
            <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>1.00000</U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
        </row>
    </Document_Lines>
    <BatchNumbers>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B1-1</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>566</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>1</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>6000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>8.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
    </BatchNumbers>
</CALL>
<CALL id="11004">
    <Document_Lines>
        <row>
            <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
            <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
            <BaseType>22</BaseType>
            <ItemCode>6327</ItemCode>
            <ShipDate>20160224</ShipDate>
            <Quantity>1884</Quantity>
            <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>1.00000</U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
        </row>
    </Document_Lines>
    <BatchNumbers>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B2-1</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>1884</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>2</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>9600.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>2500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>10.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
    </BatchNumbers>
</CALL>
<CALL id="11004">
    <Document_Lines>
        <row>
            <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
            <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
            <BaseType>22</BaseType>
            <ItemCode>2507</ItemCode>
            <ShipDate>20160224</ShipDate>
            <Quantity>4522</Quantity>
            <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>2.00000</U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
        </row>
    </Document_Lines>
    <BatchNumbers>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B3-1</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>2261</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>3</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>9600.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>2500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>12.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B3-2</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>2261</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>3</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>9600.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>2500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>12.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
    </BatchNumbers>
</CALL>
```

**Step2**

```
<BOM>
<CALL id="11003">
    <Document_Lines>
        <row>
            <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
            <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
            <BaseType>22</BaseType>
            <ItemCode>ITM08314</ItemCode>
            <ShipDate>20160224</ShipDate>
            <Quantity>3535</Quantity>
            <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>5.00000</U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
        </row>
        <row>
            <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
            <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
            <BaseType>22</BaseType>
            <ItemCode>ITM07951</ItemCode>
            <ShipDate>20160224</ShipDate>
            <Quantity>566</Quantity>
            <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>1.00000</U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
        </row>
    </Document_Lines>
    <BatchNumbers>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-1</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-2</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-3</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-4</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B0-5</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>707</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>10000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>6.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B1-1</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>566</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>1</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>6000.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>1500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>8.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
    </BatchNumbers>
</CALL>
<CALL id="11004">
    <Document_Lines>
        <row>
            <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
            <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
            <BaseType>22</BaseType>
            <ItemCode>6327</ItemCode>
            <ShipDate>20160224</ShipDate>
            <Quantity>1884</Quantity>
            <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>1.00000</U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
        </row>
        <row>
            <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
            <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
            <BaseType>22</BaseType>
            <ItemCode>2507</ItemCode>
            <ShipDate>20160224</ShipDate>
            <Quantity>4522</Quantity>
            <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>2.00000</U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
        </row>
    </Document_Lines>
    <BatchNumbers>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B2-1</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>1884</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>2</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>9600.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>2500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>10.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B3-1</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>2261</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>3</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>9600.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>2500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>12.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <BatchNumber>B3-2</BatchNumber>
            <Quantity>2261</Quantity>
            <BaseLineNumber>3</BaseLineNumber>
            <U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>9600.000000</U_SSAB_BA_LENGTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>2500.000000</U_SSAB_BA_WIDTH>
            <U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>12.000000</U_SSAB_BA_THCKNS>
        </Row>
    </BatchNumbers>
</CALL>
```

Added xslt corresponded to two Steps above

**XSLT for Step1**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/BOM/BO">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/BOM/BO/Document_Lines">
<xsl:param name="Pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:variable name="vPos1" select="position()-1"/>
        <CALL id="{BaseEntry}">
            <Document_Lines>
                <row>
                    <BaseEntry>
                        <xsl:value-of select="BaseEntry"/>
                    </BaseEntry>
                    <BaseLine>
                        <xsl:value-of select="BaseLine"/>
                    </BaseLine>
                    <BaseType>
                        <xsl:value-of select="BaseType"/>
                    </BaseType>
                    <ItemCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ItemCode"/>
                    </ItemCode>
                    <ShipDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ShipDate"/>
                    </ShipDate>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
                    </Quantity>
                    <U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
                        <xsl:value-of select="U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS"/>
                    </U_SSAB_LMA_NPCS>
                </row>
            </Document_Lines>
            <BatchNumbers>
                <xsl:for-each select="../../BatchNumbers/row[./BaseLineNumber=$vPos1]">
                    <Row>
                        <BaseLineNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()-1"/></BaseLineNumber>
                    </Row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </BatchNumbers>
        </CALL>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT for Step2**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="groups" match="/BOM/CALL" use="@id"/>
<xsl:template match="/BOM">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CALL[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', @id))]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/BOM/CALL">
    <CALL id="{@id}">
        <Document_Lines>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', @id)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="Document_Lines/*"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Document_Lines>
        <BatchNumbers>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', @id)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="BatchNumbers/*"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </BatchNumbers>
    </CALL>
</xsl:template>
```

***in the end, as you can see here, I did this in two steps, actually I want to do this in one .xsl, and have to correct the BaseLineNumber.***

[*Click here to see a full picture which visualized this question*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ged0f.jpg)

Comment: **1.** Please post your attempt to save us work. **2.** There is no "split " in XSLT 1.0, so how do you intend to get two outputs from one input? Do you use a processor that supports this as an extension (e.g. `exsl:document`)?

Comment: **3.** I could not understand what links a `BatchNumbers/row` to a specific `Document_Lines/row`. The `BaseLineNumber` values are not unique, and the `Pieces` values you called attention to are cryptic.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, See the Step2 above. I am approaching to the final result, but the BaseLineNumber are not correct, please check the last <CALL id="11004"> which contained two row under the Document_Lines(total three pieces material), so, the BaseLineNumber should be 0,1,1. each BatchNumbers/Row means one piece material.

Comment: Just a question, How to @ a person? I want to make comment that dedicated for the person. @Michael.hor257k, if Document_Lines/row/Pieces = 5, than there must be five rows under BatchNumbers, do you follow me? I know this is a little bit complex but have a closer look on the source inbound payload.

Comment: Maybe it is a job for [XProc](https://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/)

Comment: Regarding to the BaseLineNumber, something like this, for example, You have four numbers in a queue like 0,1,2,3 and if you take away the first two then the last two sequence number should be start from 0,1

Comment: "*Regarding to the BaseLineNumber...*" I am afraid that's not clear. Please provide a coherent explanation, not (only) an example.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Here below link gives you a full picture that visiualized my question. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ged0f.jpg

Comment: @Jim I am afraid you overestimate my powers of conjecture, as well as the amount of time I am willing to put into this. I suggest you make an effort to provide a step-by-step explanation how one would work out the BaseLineNumber values, if one were doing this manually (and assume that someone is not very bright).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks a lot! This question can be closed now. I figured out a way to fix the BaseLineNumber.

Comment: "*This question can be closed now.*" Only you can do that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/245750

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="row-by-BaseEntry" match="Document_Lines/row" use="BaseEntry" />

<xsl:template match="/BOM">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Document_Lines/row[count(. | key('row-by-BaseEntry', BaseEntry)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="curr-group" select="key('row-by-BaseEntry', BaseEntry)" />
            <output num="{position()}">
                <BOM>
                    <Header>
                        <row>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="Vendor"/>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="/BOM/Header/row/DocDate"/>
                        </row>
                    </Header>
                    <Document_Lines>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$curr-group"/>
                    </Document_Lines>
                    <BatchNumbers>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$curr-group">
                            <xsl:variable name="start" select="sum(preceding-sibling::row/Pieces) + 1" />
                            <xsl:variable name="end" select="$start + Pieces" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="/BOM/BatchNumbers/row[position() >= $start and position() &lt; $end]"/>                            
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </BatchNumbers>
                </BOM>
            </output>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This creates a group for each distinct `BaseEntry`, and assigns batch rows to the group based on the count of `Pieces` in each member of the group.

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <output num="1">
      <BOM>
         <Header>
            <row>
               <Vendor>V1</Vendor>
               <DocDate>20160101</DocDate>
            </row>
         </Header>
         <Document_Lines>
            <row>
               <Vendor>V1</Vendor>
               <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
               <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
               <BaseType>22</BaseType>
               <ItemCode>ITM00001</ItemCode>
               <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
               <Pieces>5.00000</Pieces>
            </row>
            <row>
               <Vendor>V1</Vendor>
               <BaseEntry>11003</BaseEntry>
               <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
               <BaseType>22</BaseType>
               <ItemCode>ITM00002</ItemCode>
               <Quantity>100</Quantity>
               <Pieces>1.00000</Pieces>
            </row>
         </Document_Lines>
         <BatchNumbers>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B0-1</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>200</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B0-2</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>200</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B0-3</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>200</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B0-4</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>200</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B0-5</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>200</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>0</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B1-1</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>100</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>1</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
         </BatchNumbers>
      </BOM>
   </output>
   <output num="2">
      <BOM>
         <Header>
            <row>
               <Vendor>V2</Vendor>
               <DocDate>20160101</DocDate>
            </row>
         </Header>
         <Document_Lines>
            <row>
               <Vendor>V2</Vendor>
               <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
               <BaseLine>0</BaseLine>
               <BaseType>22</BaseType>
               <ItemCode>ITM00008</ItemCode>
               <Quantity>200</Quantity>
               <Pieces>1.00000</Pieces>
            </row>
            <row>
               <Vendor>V2</Vendor>
               <BaseEntry>11004</BaseEntry>
               <BaseLine>1</BaseLine>
               <BaseType>22</BaseType>
               <ItemCode>ITM00009</ItemCode>
               <Quantity>1000</Quantity>
               <Pieces>2.00000</Pieces>
            </row>
         </Document_Lines>
         <BatchNumbers>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B2-1</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>200</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>2</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B3-1</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>500</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>3</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
            <row>
               <BatchNumber>B3-2</BatchNumber>
               <Quantity>500</Quantity>
               <BaseLineNumber>3</BaseLineNumber>
            </row>
         </BatchNumbers>
      </BOM>
   </output>
</root>
```

I am afraid I did not understand the requirement regarding `BaseLineNumber`.

If you need to split the result to separate documents, I suggest you ask a separate question about that (and make sure to explain which processor you are using).

Comment: thank you very much, your solution is very valuable and approaching the result. I also appended a picture at the bottom of the code example. so you will know exactly what I want to achieve.